# sdl2-sys won't compile - could not exec the linker: No such file or directory

Tags: rust, fedora, sdl-2, rust-cargo

I'm following [this Rust tutorial](http://jadpole.github.io/arcaders/2015/07/04/arcaders-1-1) and am struggling with compiling the first basic project. I am using Fedora, but am a newbie.

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling sdl2-sys v0.5.0
     Running `rustc /home/batisteo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sdl2-sys-0.5.0/build.rs --crate-name build_script_build --crate-type bin -C prefer-dynamic -g --cfg feature="default" --out-dir /home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/build/sdl2-sys-d9571ac1c4bc4261 --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/deps -Awarnings`
   Fresh libc v0.1.8
   Fresh bitflags v0.2.1
   Fresh rustc-serialize v0.3.15
   Fresh rand v0.3.8
   Fresh num v0.1.25
error: could not exec the linker `cc`: No such file or directory (os error 2)
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `sdl2-sys`.

Caused by:
  Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc /home/batisteo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sdl2-sys-0.5.0/build.rs --crate-name build_script_build --crate-type bin -C prefer-dynamic -g --cfg feature="default" --out-dir /home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/build/sdl2-sys-d9571ac1c4bc4261 --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/home/batisteo/arcade-rs/target/debug/deps -Awarnings` (exit code: 101)
```

I have the same input before or after installing SDL:

```
$ sudo dnf install SDL2-devel
```

Comment: Note the error message: "*could not exec the linker \`cc\`: No such file or directory (os error 2)*" — do you actually have `cc` installed? Can you run `cc` in the same terminal that you are running `cargo build` in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a C compiler installed? It looks to me like it's complaining about `cc`.